# Can't read a saved file in Pascal 1.9.2

Tags: pascal

```
PROGRAM archivosejercic1o;
TYPE
    num = file of integer;
VAR
    arch_num: num;
    name: string[20];
    x: integer;
BEGIN
    writeln('Type the name of the file without extension:');
    readln(name);
    name:=name+'.txt';
    Assign (arch_num,name);
    Rewrite(arch_num);
    writeln('Type in a number to add to the file:');
    readln(x);
    WHILE (x <> 0) DO BEGIN
        write(arch_num,x);
        writeln('Type in another number to add to the file:');
        readln(x);
    END;
    close(arch_num);
END.
```

I have this code which creates a file with a series of numbers that the user provides, after compiling and executing the file appears in the Pascal directory but when I open it, I get something like this:

I'm just starting to interact with archives so I'm brand new at this, if you can help me I'd be thankful.

Comment: Your "something like this" is empty.  Change `write(arch_num,x)` to `writeln(arch_num,x)` so that the `x` values are on separate lines..  Then replace your `while` loop with a `repeat ... until` loop containing an `if x <> 0 then ...` so you only call `readln(x)` in one place, inside the loop.  I'm not going to show you the exact code because you'll learn nothing.  If you get stuck doing it, ask anothe q.

Comment: What Pascal exactly? Note that there are many dialects of Pascal out there. The most popular are Delphi and FreePascal, but there are others too, like GNU Pascal (which mimics some of the others), etc. Please state the dialect you are using.

Comment: FPC 1.9.2 went out of support in 2004. Please upgrade to at least FPC 2.0 (2005)

Comment: @Marco: I guess this is [Dev-Pascal](https://www.bloodshed.net/devpascal.html), which currently has the version 1.9.2 and which is an IDE written in Delphi, using either FreePascal or GNU Pascal (AFAIK). And I assume it uses the latest of these.

Comment: Dev Pascal got version number "1.9.2" because it packed FPC 1.9.2 (which was a beta, but a very usable one), the versioning was synchronized (before it came 1.9). The GPC is more a repackaging and only came years later (iirc by a [IOI](https://ioinformatics.org/) related group?), when the IDE Project had already been stalled for years. Some educational people like the ease of setting up, and prefered it to lazarus in those days.

Comment: @Marco: thanks for the heads up. I did not download and install it and assumed it used the latest. I think that OP should rather install Lazarus. Gives you the newest FPC and the newest IDE for it. And Lazarus is quite usable, nowadays. <g>

Comment: The 1.9.x series were betas for 2.0, which added many post D2 features like dynamic arrays, variants etc. This is why they packed beta versions :-)

Answer (score 2):

### Binary vs. text

You are opening a `file of Integer`. This means that you write integers to the file, i.e. the file is in a **binary** format.

But you name it `name + '.txt'`, which suggests to me you want to write **text**, not binary values, to the file.

*Now if you display it as text, but it isn't text, you don't get what you want.*

**Binary** means that you, for instance, write a 4 byte integer like `12345` (or hex `$3039`) as those 4 bytes, i.e. the bytes `$39`, `$30`, `$00` and `$00`, in that order (or in reverse order, depending on the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your computer).

Binary is compact, but seldom human readable. If you display such a binary file as **text**, you may get weird output, or perhaps even none at all (just try to open an *.exe* file in a text editor and see what you get). You probably want to write the numbers as text. Or you use something like a hex editor to view them (if you can read hex).

So open your files as type `text`:

```
PROGRAM archivosejercic1o;
TYPE
    num = text;
VAR
    arch_num: num;
    name: string[20];
    x: integer;
BEGIN
  ...
    writeln(arch_num, x);
  ...
END.
```

---

More info on **binary** vs **text**: https://fileinfo.com/help/binary_vs_text_files. Note that that doesn't explain the different versions of Unicode text yet.

Comment: Well spotted that the OP is using a `file of Integer`, which I missed in my comment but you were too polite to point out <g>.